# c# function coding guideline

Tags: c#, coding-style

i need to pass values from one class to another and asked me what is the best way. What do you think?

a)

```
public string getValue(){
   string returnValue;
   ClassA myClass = new ClassA();
   returnValue= myClass.getValue();
   return returnValue;
}
```

b)

```
public string getValue(){
   return new ClassA().getValue(); 
}
```

I don't know if there is a problem with b like bad programming style...

Thank you!

Comment: You probably mean `return new ClassA().getValue();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler will almost certainly reduce "a" down to "b" *anyway* in release mode.

There is a case for adding intermediate variables if you are likely to want to debug with break-points at that location. But IMO "a" adds very little. I'd use "b".

Of course, you could also argue that the `new ClassA()` instance adds very little, and a static method should be provided instead. And then at that point the method **itself** is providing very little, and the caller should just call the static `ClassA.GetValue()` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming ClassA does something (a calculation, DB call, etc) and you want the result of that. One way would be to design ClassA as a static class, similar to this:

```
public static ClassA{
  public static string GetValue(){
   //magic happens here
 }
}
```

Any other class could then simply call the method:

```
var myReturnValue = ClassA.GetValue();
```